# Problem with login and HTTP POST in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I trying to implements a login system in Angular App, but it redirects to the main view and saves an empty object into Local Storage no meters what I typed into the form, a correct or fake account email and password. It's my first real project and first time to making a login system. Uniformly I don't have permission to show real API here.
The Code:

login.component.html

```
<div class="content">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Dobrodošli!</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <img class="logo" src="../../assets/dnevnimeni.svg" alt="">
        <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="email" placeholder="E-Mail" formControlName="email">
            <mat-error *nfIf="">Unesite odgovarajući E-Mail</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field> <br>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
            <mat-error *ngIf="">Unesite validan password</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field> <br>
          <button mat-stroked-button>Login</button>
        </form>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;
  error: {};
  loginError: string;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.authService.logout();
  }

  get email() { return this.loginForm.get('email'); }
  get password() { return this.loginForm.get('password'); }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.authService.login( this.email.value, this.password.value).subscribe((data) => {

       if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
            const redirect = this.authService.redirectUrl ? this.authService.redirectUrl : '/';
                this.router.navigate([redirect]);
      } else {
            this.loginError = 'email or password is incorrect.';
    }
      },
      error => this.error = error
    );
    console.log(this.authService.restaurant.email);

  }
}
```

and auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Restaurant } from '../models/Restaurant';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  loginUrl = 'xxxxxxxx';
  errorData: {};

  restaurant: Restaurant;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  redirectUrl: string;

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    var postData = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;
    return this.http.post<Restaurant>(this.loginUrl, postData)
    .pipe(map(restaurant => {
        if (restaurant) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentRestaurant', JSON.stringify(restaurant));
        }
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }


  isLoggedIn() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentRestaurant')) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  getAuthorizationToken() {
    const currentRestaurant = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentRestaurant'));
    return currentRestaurant.token;
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentRestaurant');
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {

      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {

      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
      console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }

    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    this.errorData = {
      errorTitle: 'Oops! Request for document failed',
      errorDesc: 'Something bad happened. Please try again later.'
    };
    return throwError(this.errorData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the map function you don't return any value and try to transform in object the parameters that sends in the post request;

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
let postData = {email : email ,password :password};
return this.http.post<Restaurant>(this.loginUrl, postData)
.pipe(map(restaurant => {
    if (restaurant) {
      localStorage.setItem('currentRestaurant', JSON.stringify(restaurant));
      return restaurant;
    }
  }),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! However, the login can pass even with incorrect email and password, it doesn't show anything in view because of an empty object, but still can pass to the main page. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Your post data should be like var postData = {email : email ,password :password} , but you have described get request with query parameters.
Also saving data in observable data stream is bad practice. Each new subscriber  triggers execution of this code  again

```
        if (restaurant) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentRestaurant', JSON.stringify(restaurant));
        }
```

Comment: when I tried it, on console I get "Cannot read property 'email' of undefined"

Comment: it means exceptions is here  console.log(this.authService.restaurant.email); restaurant value is not set for authService.

Comment: Elso console.log(this.authService.restaurant.email) should be inside subcription if your api returns  restaurant result type

Answer (score 0):

`postData` should be the object instead of string. also check by `console.log` in `isLoggedIn()` method, what data `localStorage.getItem('currentRestaurant')` returns, if it has a value like `"{}"` or `"null"` it will return true in if statement.

```
isLoggedIn() {
if (localStorage.getItem('currentRestaurant')) {
  return true;
}
return false; }
```